# How do you configure the endpoint for Amazon S3 by using the AWS SDK V2?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In AWS SDK V1, I set up my credentials as:

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(Credentials.access_key, Credentials.secret_access_key);
```

And then set the endpoint as:

```
EndpointConfiguration endpoint = new EndpointConfiguration("<endpoint URL>", "<region>");
```

And then created the client as:

```
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(endpoint)
            .build();
```

How do I set up this same client using AWS SDK V2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the Javadocs here:

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/client/builder/SdkClientBuilder.html#endpointOverride-java.net.URI-

See:

**endpointOverride**

endpointOverride(URI endpointOverride)

Configure the endpoint with which the SDK should communicate.**

Looks like you can create a **URI** object and pass that when you create the Service client

```
URI myURI = new URI("<endpoint URL>");

  Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
  S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(region)
                .endpointOverride(myURI)
                .build();
```

Answer (score -2):

To use Cloudflare R2 storage with software.amazon.awssdk.s3 2.20.x the region needs to be set to "auto" and endpointOverride needs to be set:

```
AwsBasicCredentials awsBasicCredentials =
            AwsBasicCredentials.create(ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
    S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(
                    StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsBasicCredentials))
            .region(Region.of("auto"))
            .endpointOverride(URI.create("https://<accountid>.r2.cloudflarestorage.com"))
            .build();
```

For legacy applications, if u want to use Cloudflare R2 with 1.12.x u need to specify the endpoint as "auto" lowercase:

```
  AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(
                            new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                                    new BasicAWSCredentials(
                                            ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)))
                    .withEndpointConfiguration(
                            new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("https://<accountid>.r2.cloudflarestorage.com", "auto"))
                    .build();
```