# How can we use minio storage as same as s3 url

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, minio

How can we use minio storage as same as S3. Is there any need to change the code of java spring boot?. Previous codes are aws related. I don't want to change the code, But i want to access the storage from another source. Is that possible with minio.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you are using the aws-java-sdk s3client. Therefore you just need to set the endpoint-configuration (for example http://localhost:9000, if minio runs on port 9000 on your local machine)

For more infos about the endpoint-configuration, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68005239/how-do-you-configure-the-endpoint-for-amazon-s3-by-using-the-aws-sdk-v2)